# How to export two ICollections (questions and answers to them) into IBM SPSS format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, spss

I have 2 `Icollections`(already initilized all data is in them already):

- `ICollection<Question> questions`
- `ICollection<Answer> answers`

One  contains questions with unique ID, the second answers. Every answer has a numeric value.

They look like this

```
  public class Question {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string QuestionText { set; get; } 
        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { set; get; }

    }
    public class Answer {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public string AnswerText { set; get; }
        public Double Value { get; set; }
        public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to export this data to IBM SPSS, the issue is that there is no examples how to do this and this is the simplest example anyone could think of.

I also found .NET SDK for IBM SPSS but there are not examples too.

**NOTE** I will make export in ASP.NET MVC 5.1 application so it might be important, I don't know if their sdk will work on Azure.

Comment: Have you seen [spss](http://spss.codeplex.com/) on codeplex? (There is a [SimpleDemo](http://spss.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SimpleDemo/) project which appears to make use of DataTables)

Comment: @BradChristie That might help, I do not know VB but I might understand it. Thank you.